# how to rewrite this c++ simple code?

Tags: c++, input, url-rewriting, output

the code bellow is a c++ code that works just perfectly, the teacher asked us to rewrite it in order to have the input and output in only one instruction.

i really don´t know how to, and i have done research for hours.

i'll really appreciate a hint on how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;
    cin >> c;

    std;

    if(c == 0) {
        cout << "user sent 0" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "user sent a number different from 0" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for reading.

Comment: by instruction you mean separate function?

Comment: thats exactly what i was wondering, that's all the info the teacher gave us.

Comment: Is it mean to be badly formatted ? Is that part of the point of the question, perhaps ?

Comment: Actually, the code does **not** work perfectly! When you enter something which isn't an integer, the input fails and you read an uninitialized `int` which results in undefined behavior! You **always** need to check if the input was successful, e.g. using `if (std::cin >> c) { successful_input(); } else { input_failed(); }` (obviously doing something sensible instead of the two functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your teacher considers an if-else statement as one instruction, I can propose this one:

```
#include <iostream >
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int c;
    if ( (cin >> c) && c==0 ) 
        cout << ”user sent 0” << endl ;
    else cout << ”user sent a number different from 0” << endl ; 
    return 0; 
}
```

If he sees it more strictly,  then you can try :

```
    int c;
    cout << ( (cin >> c) && c==0  ? "user sent 0" : "user sent a number different from 0"  ) << endl;  
    return 0;
```

Conceptually, I love the last one.  But when I read it again, it reminds me  B.Kernighan's famous quote :  "*Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.*"

Answer (score 1):

This is the smallest I can do:

```
   std::cout << (std::cin.get() == '0' ? "user sent 0" : "user sent a number different from 0");
```